# Windows 7 unable to render sound via headphones

Tags: windows-7, audio, troubleshooting, speakers

I have a dual boot laptop. When in Ubuntu, both the laptop speakers and the headphones work flawlessly.

However, in Windows 7, the sound is only coming from the laptop speakers, and not the headphones. Any suggestions on how to resolve this.

P.S: I have uninstalled/re-installed Realtek HD Audio Manager. Updated the drivers for the audio. The Windows troubleshooting also could not resolve the issue(big surprise there!!)

Answer (score 0):

It seems its not the connection as the headphones work fine in Ubuntu.  Must be a windows or driver setting...

Have you set the headphones (line out) setting as default in windows?
Are you sure its using one of the "digital audio" devices? - or do you have multiple audio out jacks perhaps?

This happens to me a bit as I do alot of video editing and change speakers and inputs around, and I use an external soundcard too - its usually something like the default setting that fixes it for me (Your line out isn't muted somehow?)

Good luck - it be a right pain to figure out sometimes!

Comment: Yes, you are partly there already, may be if you see my laptop you could have fixed it... Point is, since sometime I had to disable and enable the "audio driver" for the sound to come (earlier unless I did this, there would be no sound coming out of the laptop).... Last night, I tried a couple of things with my laptop, but the sound wouldn't budge. May be I need to uninstall and re-install the audio driver again to check(??)

Comment: And yes, the default is the line out..